# How to Hide Product Information from Woocommerce Checkout Page?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, checkout

my store is running with woocommerce 3.5.1 and sshop theme, I want to hide the product details/informations only from checkout page not from cart. Store URL is https://techcart.pk Please help. Image is attached for reference.

[image: Cart details]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Add these CSS rules to your theme's stylesheet (or via **Customizer > Additional CSS**):

```
.woocommerce-checkout .woocommerce-checkout-review-order-table thead,
.woocommerce-checkout .woocommerce-checkout-review-order-table tbody { display: none; }
```